# How can you implement disable auto update in your app?

Tags: android, android-service, android-settings

How can you implement disable auto update in your app?

I have an app, and on the settings page there is a Boolean value with enables auto update or not.

Is there a tutorial on the code of disabling auto update for your app?

Additional: Is it possible to set the Google Play settings by code? I know that Google Play has an option to disable auto update.

Comment: AFAIK, there is no way for you to control this, except perhaps from a rooted device.

Comment: @AFAIK see the additional comments I added.

Comment: "Is it possible to set the google play settings by code?" -- if there is, that would be a serious security flaw.

Comment: I have seem under Settings for some app in google play, they have an option for check for updates.

Comment: I wonder how did they did it.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. It's as simple as that. Sorry.

Comment: see the additional comments I added.