# React Native - disable auto update app programmatically

Tags: android, google-play

When uploading an app to Google Play, can we avoid the app from updating?

I found some useful links saying that we can't:

- [Disable Auto Update programmatically in Android 3 (Honeycomb)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9654619/auto-update-disable-programmatically-in-android-honeycomb)
- [How can you implement disable auto update in your app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21386840/how-to-implement-disable-auto-update-on-your-app)

However, these questions have been asked for a long time. Is
there a way to do it?

Comment: Those answers are still relevant today, app updating is handled by the Google Play app. There is nothing you can do about it

Comment: @tyczj: thank you for verify those answer are still available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Auto update an app programmatically

I think it is not possible, but you have another option when
at app opening.

In the splash screen, you check the app version from the back-end version and if the app version both are the same then the app will go the next screen.

If both versions are not same then the app will be go in the update screen. Put the button update app there and go to the play store app link.

Comment: thank you for your answer. The problem is that when there is a new version on Google Play, the app will update automatically. Following, I want to disable that function so that users can update manually.